# Connecting my Android App to a database

Tags: java, android, mysql, servlets

I am new to Android and am trying to create an App which can connect to a database.

**Web Server** = Apache Tomcat

**Database** = MySQL

**Web Service** = HTTP Requests and Servlets?

I have never used PHP before, is there a way that I can connect to the database using only Servlets?

Also, would I need a JDBC Driver and SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you need JDBC driver to connect to mysql DB on your servlet side, but if you're using MySQL, why you need SQL server for?? you can take a look at this [blog post](http://www.veereshr.com/Android/AndroidToServlet) on how to send request from your android app to servlet.